# Jquery Mobile custom button image

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, jquery-mobile

I have a button:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="mapa" data-theme="a">Vidi Mapu</a>
```

With this CSS:

```
.ui-icon-mapa {
    background-image: url("images/mapa.png") !important;
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 26px 21px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 35px;
}
```

Problem is that button doesnt show an image/icon at all.
I used every possible solution but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `button`'s image using a `class` but don't set any `class` to `a`. so set `class=.ui-icon-mapa` like following:

```
$('a[data-icon=mapa]').addClass('.ui-icon-mapa'); // using jQuery
```

or if possible then directly using HTML like:

```
<a class="ui-icon-mapa" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="mapa" data-theme="a">Vidi Mapu</a>
```

Or

in your CSS try:

```
a[data-icon="mapa"].ui-icon-mapa {
    background-image: url("images/mapa.png") !important;
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 26px 21px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 35px;
}
```

#### Note

Check that the given CSS property is overwritten later by other CSS or not!

Comment: @DaliborVlaho You any debugger to inspect the CSS and check that is has the image background or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `class="ui-icon-mapa"` in html, or `a[data-icon="mapa"]` in css

Comment: I was try that too but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of JQM you are using, but in 1.3 version this can be done in following way.

First you need to make CSS class:

```
    .ui-icon-tipwin-download {
    background-image: url("images/other/download_app_icon_18x18.png");
}
```

Then in your HTML markup you can use this icon in buttons following way:

```
 <a href='javascript:void();' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='tipwin-download'>Download</a>
```

Note **data-icon** attribute, it is second part of our css class **tipwin-download**.

This works for me just fine.
It could be that you have to big icon also.